# Are static members seperate then non static members?

Tags: java, non-static, static

So I got this class:

```
package src;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Model {
    public List<Vector3f> Vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    public List<Vector3f> Normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    public List<Face> Faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

    public static Model LoadModel()
    {
        return new Model();
    }
}
```

Will the LoadModel method affect any Model objects? The LoadModel method is not done yet!

Comment: What do you mean by "affect" ?

Comment: In the given code, calling `Model.LoadModel()` is *equivalent* to calling `new Model()`. Now, will `LoadModel` do something *with* the new model instance before it returns it? That's up to you, really ..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question, mate.

LoadModel is a static method - that means the method "belongs" to the class. In simple words, someone can do this:

```
     Model model = Model.LoadModel();
```

The LoadModel will create a Model object - which will instantiate the Vertices, Normals and Faces objects.

So short answer: no, it won't affect - it will only cause the Model object and its inner objects to be instantiated and the new instance of the Model will be returned to the caller.

Hope I've answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Are static members seperate then non static members?

Yes. They are associated with the class, not with an individual instance.

> Will the LoadModel method affect any Model objects?

It will create a new one.

> The LoadModel method is not done yet!

I have no idea what this means.